# How to get started with UX design when hiring freelance experts?

Tags: website-design, mobile, information-architecture, blog

I am a business operator who own number of blogs. I am looking to hire a freelance UX consultant to get started creating amazing design. I would like to understand the process behind this.

Many say we need to hire UX / Information architect to first figure out a wireframe and then give this wireframe to a graphics designer who will convert the wireframe into proper design. Which would then go to the developer for coding.

Can any one explain me the step by step process?

P.S: My blog design is quite complicated involving multiple function and user journey. So, this isn't an ordinary blog design work.

Comment: There is no one step-by-step process. What you describe is common, but certainly not the only way to go about it

Comment: Or you can simply get a developer who can do everything.  We are out there. =D

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you are looking for is someone who can help you to understand what you really need. Looks like everyone around you is screaming buzzwords like UX, Design and all that stuff, and you want to keep your blogs trendy and don't know were to start.

If you want to really understand the process that goes behind creating a great user experience, I would advise you to read [The Elements of User Experience](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321683684).

I'm sorry I can't point you in a particular direction, but I think the most important part is understanding your customers and iterating until you find a good enough solution that satisfies your customers. For that you can read [Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321965515), this will teach you how to make things simpler for your customers, and Rocket Surgery Made Easy (from the same author) that teaches you how to perform user tests.

Of course, if you manage blogs, you should also get some real feedback from the field, and for that you can try using google analytics.

Comment: I think part of his struggle is that frequently you can find a person who can make things pretty, but it's difficult to find someone who is qualified at making things usable, and easy. I wonder if there is actually a marketplace for that. I'm honestly also curious.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato I agree with you. I think that you have a marketplace for both skills but usually clients want something flashy to show on a demo. It is still difficult to sell "we have spent 3 months making the product easier to use" inside most organisations.

Comment: It's possible there's just a need for more UI/UX propaganda.